# Connecting to MySQL DB from various hosts

Tags: mysql, security

How to add a host to MySQL's list of hosts it can accept connections from.

Comment: Lot's of programmers install and run their own MySQL DBMSs. So kicking off to superuser is perhaps a little harsh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://www.linuxhelp.net/guides/mysql/:

> To give localhost permission to access
>   all databases, enter this:
>
> ```
> mysql> insert into 
>          -> host(host,db,Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, 
>          -> Delete_priv, Create_priv, Drop_priv)
>          -> values('localhost','%','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y');
> ```
>
> Note, the '%' can be replaced with a
>   database name. The '%' is a wildcard.
>
> Following the previous format, to
>   allow access from another hostname (in
>   this case "windowsbox") add this:
>
> ```
> mysql> insert into 
>          -> host(host,db,Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, 
>          -> Delete_priv, Create_priv, Drop_priv)
>          -> values('windowsbox','%','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y');
> ```
>
> Again, '%' is used as a Wild-Card.
>
> To create a user 'djg' who can access
>   the MySQL server from localhost, type
>   this:
>
> ```
> mysql> insert into 
>          -> user (host, user, password)
>          -> values('localhost','djg',password('mypassword'));
> ```
>
> To give the user access from another
>   hostname, domain, etc... add other
>   entries accordingly. For example, to
>   give user djg access from windowsbox:
>
> ```
> mysql> insert into 
>          -> user (host, user, password)
>          -> values('windowsbox','djg',password('mypassword'));
> ```
>
> Now... to give the user permissions to
>   access a database from localhost, add
>   this entry and change with your
>   appropriate information:
>
> ```
> mysql> insert into
>       -> db (host,db,user,Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv,  Create_priv, Drop_priv)
>       -> values ('localhost','mydatabase','djg','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y');
> ```
>
> To give the user permissions from
>   windowsbox, add this:
>
> ```
> mysql> insert into
>       -> db (host,db,user,Select_priv, Insert_priv, Update_priv, Delete_priv, Create_priv, Drop_priv)
>       -> values ('windowsbox','mydatabase','djg','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y','Y');
> ```

PS: don't forget to flush privileges

Answer (score 1):

The information on the host a user is allowed to connect from is in the `user` table, see [adding users](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html). Also make sure that you are not blocking connections on a firewall/os level.